# Angular Adding new item on Array when length is = 0

Tags: angularjs

How do i add a new item in an empty array using angular? Here's what i've got

```
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="arr.lenght == 0 || arr[0] = ''">
        <div ng-repeat="d in arr track by $index">
          <input ng-model="arr[$index]" />
        </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you do it in controller.

### HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="mainControllerInit()">
    <div ng-repeat="d in arr track by $index">
      <input ng-model="arr[$index]" />
    </div>
</body>
```

### In Controller

```
$scope.arr = [];
$scope.mainControllerInit = function(){
   if(!$scope.arr.length){
      $scope.arr[0] = '';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="(!arr || arr.lenght == 0) ? arr = [''] : ''">
    <div ng-repeat="d in arr track by $index">
       <input ng-model="arr[$index]" />
    </div>
 </body>
```

Well you can also do this in your `MainCtrl` that will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the array properly. Also you are performing comparison inside ng-init. ng-init is meant for initialization.

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="arr=[]; arr.length=0">
  <input ng-model="arr[0]" />
  <p> {{arr[0]}} </p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ttQA/554/)